# Java Filter through CSV and look for Gaps in Data

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv

I am a little stuck here and need some advice for how best to solve my problem:
I have a CSV file with a lot of sales data in it(402,000+ lines). **When there are no sales for a certain product in a store, there is no data.**

***`Therefore I want to find those periods where there are no sales for a product in a store > 3 days and add them to a watchlist(file/list).`***

The unique identifier is the SKU + storename combined. So for example the SKU+storename would be *801Whangarei PAK n SAVE*. And its missing sales from the 5/03/2019 to 7/03/2019 and I would want that added to a list.

The data looks as below:
[Sales data file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upnLI.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String line;
String[] elements;
String storename;
String sku;
String date;

    BufferedReader order_lines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("order_lines_file.csv"));
    int counter = 0;
    while ((line = order_lines.readLine()) != null){
        counter++;
        elements = line.split(",");
            date = elements[5].trim();
            storename = elements[2].trim();
            sku = elements[1].trim();
            String key = storename + sku;
            System.out.println(key);
    }
    System.out.println("End Of File Reached");  
}
```

}

I have really only got as far as reading the file as I know I will just end up wasting a long time trying to figure this out.

Pseudocode would look something like this:

```
FOREACH (Unique( sku + storename) IN Sales data){ 
if((current date - next date) > 3 days){
 list.add(dates between current date & next date ) 
}
else{ next date = current date 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Are you open/able to use a database here?

Comment: Not at the moment - However, I am looking to store this sales data file in an SQL database sometime in the near future.

Comment: Well you are asking for an operation which is fairly well suited to a database.  So, that would be my preferred way of answering your question.

Comment: Are you able to explain briefly how this could be solved with a database? Might help me make the transition if its rather trivial.

Comment: One general database strategy would be left joining a calendar table to a table having your data.  This would easily reveal the missing dates.

Comment: @WillEyedowin, can you please elaborate the conditions you want ?

Comment: @SachithDickwella I want a list that shows where there is sales data missing for a SKU in a Region on certain dates. In the sales data file, there is no data(a gap) for when a SKU in a Region does not sell anything. So, in my head you could do it a few ways: Filter through the CSV while looking at one SKU + Region and finding what the next date that product sells. If that date is 3 days or more different, then add those dates to a list and move on. Or you create a unique list of sales for each SKU+ region and sort it by date then calculate differences between each row.

Comment: @SachithDickwella in the photo I linked - there is one example of this(Theres likely thousands). The bottom 2 lines show that this SKU in this Region has no sales data between the 4/03/2019 to 8/03/2019. I would add: 801Whangarei PAKnSAVE 5/03/2019, 801Whangarei PAKnSAVE 6/03/2019,801Whangarei PAKnSAVE 7/03/2019 all to a list as they have no sales data. Hope that helps?

Comment: Heres some pseudo code:

FOREACH (CONCAT(SKU,Region) IN Sales data){ 
If((current date - next date) > 3 days){
     list.add(dates between current date & next date )
else{
next date = current date
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just sorting the data by SKU + storename then by date - this means the next line will hold the next available sales data for that SKU+storename. If the next date is more than 3 days from the current line date then add that to a seperate file.

Here is the question I asked which helped me: [JAVA Sort CSV file by columns and then by a date column correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55232791/java-sort-csv-file-by-columns-and-then-by-a-date-column-correctly)